# Grab XML from WSO2 governance

Tags: java, xml, wso2

I'm in the final stages of a project to allow users to use the Management Console to upload services to WSO2 governance. Once a month, we want to grab all info from WSO2 and transform into HTML and post to a wiki.

At the moment, I haven't found a convient way to export all XML from WSO2 governance through Java. The only solution I found was to grab all services with a certain tag. This is not going to work well if there are other users that do not know to add this tag.

Does any one have any ideas on how I can export the XML from all services on my WSO2 instance?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all resources stored in governance registry?

Comment: Yes, I need all resources that have been uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in code here: http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-invoke-custom-artifacts-using.html#!/2013/02/how-to-invoke-custom-artifacts-using.html

I needed to get the info from the artifact, not the individual resources.
GenericArtifactManager artifactManager = new GenericArtifactManager(registry, "applications");

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply call Registry.getResource() method to retrieve resources..Check the Governance Registry API for available methods..So, you can use any of them which suits to your need..